# Get size of a process' readable memory?

Tags: winapi, memory

How can I get the range of all readable memory in a process?

VirtualQuery only allows me to query pages at a time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to just get a list of readable pages. You need to iterate through all the memory (starting from the lowest address containing valid memory) with VirtualQuery. You can read the RegionSize from the MEMORY-BASIC_INFORMATION structure to know what base address to call at.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to iterate over each memory region.

This code will do that, and output the start and end address of each region:

```cpp
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    unsigned char* addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << " end : 0x" << std::hex << (uintptr_t)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize << "\n";
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }
```